# How to calculate the Expectation of a sufficient statistic

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ follow an exponential family of distribution with the density function $f_{\theta}(x) = a(\theta)h(x)exp\{T(x)^T \theta\}$, where $\theta \in R^k$, $a(\theta), h(x)$ are given functions. Find the mean of $T(x)$.

I don't know what I need to do next step after I write the joint density function. Any help or hint is welcome

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Moments_and_cumulants_of_the_sufficient_statistic.

Comment: Still confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea, as it presented in the wiki link in the comments, is that you cannot compute it directly. Namely,
\begin{align}
E[T(X)] = \int_x a(\theta) T(x)  \exp\{T(x)\theta\} dx
\end{align}
note that $ T(x)  \exp\{T(x)\theta\} = \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\exp\{T(x)\theta\}$, hence, under mild regularity conditions, you can interchange between the integral and the derivative, i.e.,
\begin{align}
E[T(X)] & = \int_x a(\theta)  \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\exp\{T(x)\theta\} dx\\
& = a(\theta)\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\int_x   \exp\{T(x)\theta\} dx
\end{align}
now recall that, by definition of a proper density function, $\int_x  \exp\{T(x)\theta\} = 1 / a(\theta) $, thus
$$
E[T(X)] = a(\theta) \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} \frac{1}{a(\theta)} = - \frac{a'(\theta)}{ a (\theta)} = - \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} \ln ( a ( \theta)) 
$$